# How can I make menu show up on custom action bar?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, menu

I created a custom tool bar to use in my application

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout_height=""
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView14"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_24" />

       
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

I inserted it into my mainActivity resource file

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I have also:

```
Toolbar mainToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);    setSupportActionBar(mainToolBar);
```

After overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` , I got the menu inflater and inflated the menu. Still my menu is not showing up on the top right corner of the activity.

Comment: have you added onCreateOptionsMenu method in activity?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from the `android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"` in the tool bar

Change it to a custom theme in your app
For example:

```
 <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

and add it to the ToolBar `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme"`

Check out this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LD2zsCAAVXw) to understand better.